# No Module Name 'pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.PlotItem.plotConfigTemplate_pyqt5' while executing exe

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller, pyqtgraph

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.PlotItem.plotConfigTemplate_pyqt5'
[13260] Failed to execute script main
```

provided by this error when executing an exe created using pyinstaller,
i have tried using --hidden-import but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to either

- An incompatibility in your PyQt/pyqtgraph libraries or
- A regression in pyqtgraph in version >=0.12

You can view the "Qt bindings test matrix" on the GitHub page for pyqtgrph to see if you are compliant. In my case, I was using python3.8 and PyQt5-5.15, which have passing tests. I still saw the error you report.

Rolling back pyqtgraph to 0.11 is what worked for me.